Getting Different Explain Results On The Same Query After Upgrading to MySQL 8
Hi I have a query that runs as below:
SELECT COUNT(`contacts`.`contact_id`) AS non_interactive
FROM `contacts`
    INNER JOIN `contacts_lists_mappings`
        ON `contacts`.`contact_id` = `contacts_lists_mappings`.`cmapping_contact_id`
WHERE (
  `contacts`.`contact_status` = 'on' AND
  `contacts`.`contact_email_status` IN ('none','always send') AND
  `contacts`.`contact_deleted` = 'no' AND
  `contacts_lists_mappings`.`cmapping_list_id` = '' AND
  `contacts_lists_mappings`.`cmapping_email_status` != 'unsubscribed' AND
  `contacts_lists_mappings`.`cmapping_contact_id` NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `stats_contact_link_clicks`.`clink_contact_id`
    FROM `stats_contact_link_clicks`
    INNER JOIN `messages_lists_mappings`
    ON `stats_contact_link_clicks`.`clink_message_id` = `messages_lists_mappings`.`mlist_message_id`
    WHERE `messages_lists_mappings`.`mlist_list_id` = ''
  ) AND `contacts_lists_mappings`.`cmapping_contact_id` NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `stats_contact_reads`.`read_contact_id`
    FROM `stats_contact_reads`
    INNER JOIN `messages_lists_mappings`
    ON `stats_contact_reads`.`read_message_id` = `messages_lists_mappings`.`mlist_message_id`
    WHERE `messages_lists_mappings`.`mlist_list_id` = ''
  )
 )

This query runs quick on one instance and the explain result for the quick instance are as below:
Fast query explain image
But on the slow instance the explain shows as below:
Slow query explain image
Please assist on what could be a potential issue.

Getting different explain results on an upgrade is not an 'issue' and is an expression of changes to the optimizer. I'm afraid you need to review your code and the upgrade documentation.
